# SignalR connect to client from server

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr

is it possible to connect to a client from a server using SignalR if I know the IP/Port the client is running on? All examples I see online are about clients connecting to servers. But I need it the other way around as all my configuration is stored in the server application (like the IPs/Ports of all clients).

Comment: I dont think that will work, Server has defined a port on which it listens to. So clients have to connect to that port and no other port will work (because signalr server does not recognise these packets are for him). I think, the only way to solve your problem, would be that you run the Hubs on the clients, and  the server is connecting to these defined Hubs - ip, port).

Comment: No, this is not the way this sort of technology works, its client/server not server/sever client/client. also how are you going to punch through the clients firewalls and security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original scenario for SignalR is for web servers to be able to push data out to connected clients. This means you don't know the IP address. Your visitors might be using all kinds of devices and connections. It feels like what you're trying to do here is (ab)use SignalR for a more traditional client-server scenario.

What you're trying to do can be done very easy using the [Socket class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket).

You can find some [examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples).

Comment: Thanks, after playing around a bit with the Socket class, I think this would be the most viable solution.